# Which websites support U2F?

Tags: u2f

FIDO Alliance's Universal 2nd Factor (U2F) is a new and promising approach to replace passwords. The FIDO Alliance comprises of many players but so far only Google website seems to support it. Are there other websites I can use to login with my U2F token?

Comment: GitHub now supports U2F tokens for 2-step verification.

Answer (score 24):

Here [www.dongleauth.info](http://www.dongleauth.info) is list of websites,
self-hosted software and USB dongles compatible to U2F (as well as One
Time Passwords)

Answer (score -2):

There is no websites that support it yet except for Google and propably a very few other. The main reason is that only Chrome has U2F support. Once more browsers implement U2F support, I Think more websites will implement U2F.